# Warning C26454: Arithmetic overflow: '-' operation produces a negative unsigned result at compile time (io.5)

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, treecontrol

Code analysis:

```
ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB_HISTORY_TYPE,
  &CAssignHistoryDlg::OnTcnSelchangeTabHistoryType)
```

Warning C26454:

> Arithmetic overflow: '-' operation produces a negative unsigned result
>   at compile time (io.5).

The definition of `TCN_SELCHANGE` is:

```
#define TCN_FIRST (0U-550U)
#define TCN_SELCHANGE           (TCN_FIRST - 1)
```

I can't see what else I can do!

Comment: Infact I get LOTS of these errors. Never used used to. So things have changed in VC.

Comment: They should have used `#define TCN_FIRST 0xFFFFFDDA` instead of trying to be fancy. You can redefine the constants (not always a good idea) or use `#pragma warning push/pop` to hide the warning.

Comment: FYI: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/285656/warning-c26454-arithmetic-overflow-operation-produ.html

Comment: You should mention in your submission that this is a "Code Analysis warning" not a compiler warning.

Comment: The irony here is that this was probably a result of someone trying to make those constants compile quietly at warning level 4.  If `TCN_FIRST` had been defined as `-550U`, then you'd get a compile time warning (because it's suspicious to apply unary minus to an unsigned value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to subtract a larger unsigned value from a smaller unsigned value and it's causing the result to wrap past zero. In your case, I assume `TCN_FIRST` is defined as 0 so setting `TCN_SELCHANGE` to one will fix the problem.

You should also be using `constexpr` or `const` instead of defines anyway.

According to MSDN:

[Arithmetic overflow checks in C++ Core Check](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/02/23/arithmetic-overflow-checks-in-c-core-check/)

> [C26451 RESULT_OF_ARITHMETIC_OPERATION_CAST_TO_LARGER_SIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c26451) :[operator] operation wraps past 0 and produces a large unsigned number at compile time. This warning indicates that the subtraction operation produces a negative result which was evaluated in an unsigned context. This causes the result to wrap past 0 and produce a really large unsigned number, which can result in unintended overflows.

```
1 // Example source:
2 unsigned int negativeunsigned() {
3    const unsigned int x = 1u - 2u; // C26454 reported here
4    return x;
5 }

1 // Corrected source:
2 unsigned int negativeunsigned() {
3     const unsigned int x = 4294967295; // OK
4     return x;
5 }
```

> In the corrected source, a positive value was assigned to the unsigned result.

Comment: But these are not my defines. They are Microsoft defines.

Comment: they are part of the common control header: `#define TCN_FIRST               (0U-550U)`.

Answer (score 8):

```
//windows header file:
#define TCN_FIRST (0U-550U)
#define TCN_SELCHANGE           (TCN_FIRST - 1)

//user file:
...
unsigned int i = TCN_SELCHANGE;
```

Above code is valid in C++, it should compile without any warning. There is no overflow, that's just meant to be `-550U` It would be more clear if they wrote it as `#define TCN_FIRST 0xFFFFFDDA` or `0xFFFFFFFFU-549U`

Code Analysis seems to uses a different method and sees an overflow.

Possible solution:

Disable the warning in code:

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 26454 )

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB1, OnTcnSelchangeTabHistoryType)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

#pragma warning( pop )
```

Or, disable the warning in Code Analysis rule
[Use the code analysis rule set editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/working-in-the-code-analysis-rule-set-editor)

[image]

Comment: I have no Configure menu item.

Comment: This helped: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set. I had to right-click the project and go into properties. Get to it that way.

Comment: It works. In my case the other ones that are still showing that never used to are: C264XX  34, 39, 51 and 95.

Comment: It gets a bit messy either way. It would be nice if Microsoft can find a fix for it, rather than disabling the warning altogether.

Comment: I agree. They are rasing things that shouldn't be raised. Particularly when it is their code. Like my other question where a method calls the base then the base method has not been hidden because it has specifically been called.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started using MFC dialogs and have the same problem as above when using `TVN_SELCHANGED` (it generates 0-58U), which comes from:

> `#define TVN_SELCHANGEDW (TVN_FIRST-51)` found in `commctrl.h` **from Microsoft**.

However, it does not cause the program to fail compilation. I think that preventing that error message, may cause other headaches if an actual math operation is really a problem. I suppose redefining the constant is a (slightly) better way to go (provided a good comment is provided for future reference), unless you are using lots of these constants.

Comment: I have no intention of changing any MFC defined constants. It is something I have to live with. It is up to Microsoft as to whether the update the SDK to have more appropriate values. But we are talking 5 years now, so I doubt it. 

Comment: I also mention the same definition as a comment to my question. 