# Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value then casting the result to a 8 byte value

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to solve a quadratic equation whose coefficients' values do not exceed 100 by absolute value and it is guaranteed that if any roots exist, they are integers. Here's what I've tried:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a, b, c;  // coefficients of quadratic equation
  std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
  int d = b * b - 4 * a * c;  // discriminant

  if (d < 0)
    std::cout << "No roots";
  else if (d == 0)
    std::cout << "One root: " << -b / (2 * a);
  else
    std::cout << "Two roots: " << (-b - std::sqrt(d)) / (2 * a) << " "
              << (-b + std::sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);

  return 0;
}
```

It works fine, however, Visual Studio 2019 shows this warning:

> Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2).

[image]

Exactly why does this warning pop up and what is it trying to tell me? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix the problem?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995817/warning-c26451-arithmetic-overflow) on SO, but I don't believe it's a bug.

Comment: Why do you think this is different from the linked question? It seems to me to be the exact same situation.

Comment: I don't like the word "casting", as there isn't any. One would expect compiler creators to know the difference between implicit and explicit conversion.

Comment: *and it is guaranteed that if any roots exist, they are integers.* -- You may [want to read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655668/are-all-integer-values-perfectly-represented-as-doubles).

Comment: It's not actually a bug. It's saying that `2 * a` results in a 32-bit value, which, depending on the value of `a`, might overflow. Since the result gets converted into a 64-bit value (for the division), it is suggesting you convert prior to the multiplication. You can fix it by doing `2.0 * a` or `2LL * a`

Comment: _"I don't believe it's a bug."_ Why not? If you have a criticism of a question or answer on that page you should give it on that page rather than re-asking the same question.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, perhaps poorly phrased, but I wouldn't say it's wrong. It is warning you about a potential overflow when it is going to have to widen its type anyway; which I think is a fair warning. Just `double result = ( 2 * a );` generates the same warning.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica it's not a bug. if `a` is INT_MAX for example, `2 * a` would overflow, but `2.0 * a` wouldn't. And the result is converted to `double` anyway for the division. So `2.0 * a` essentially gives the same result but it is much less likely to overflow.

Comment: Hmmmm actually yeah okay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning C26451: Arithmetic overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995817/warning-c26451-arithmetic-overflow)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug. Here:

```
(-b - std::sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
```

The result of the expression is a `double`. But result of `2 * a` is an `int` and it's eventually converted to a `double`. It is possible that `2 * a` overflows if `a` is too large before it's converted to `double`. But since the eventual result is already a `double`, you could cast `2` or `a` to `double` as well and avoid the risk of overflow once and for all. So the compiler is telling you that the Right Thing<sup>TM</sup> to do is:

```
(-b - std::sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a)
```

It won't overflow (result of `(2.0 * a)` is a `double`) and it's probably already what you want.

Comment: Good explanation! But I want to add one remark: the compiler is not telling you want the Right Thing to do is. It's merely indicating a _possible_ problem and having _you_ decide how to deal with it. Static analyzers are not about true or false (good or bad code). I think they work best if you see them as a colleague that's asking you (without knowing all the details that you know): "have you really thought about this?" In some cases an additional cast can make the compiler warning go away (and also let your reviewing colleague know that you really thought about the statement).

Answer (score 3):

The root cause here (pun very much accepted) is that the quadratic equation is not a [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation). It applies to real numbers, and in particular `sqrt(d)` is usually not an integer.

In C++, the return type of `sqrt(IntegralType)` is `double`. Thus `2*a` is converted to `double` too, but only after multiplying. And Visual Studio very reasonably notes that you're better off doing the conversion before multiplying. It just doesn't note that you can even make `a,b,c` all doubles from the start.

Comment: Why does it recommend doing conversion *before* multiplying?

Comment: @khaliyeva: Multiplying two integers can overflow; converting them to `double` certainly won't, and multiplying the resulting `double`s won't overflow either. E.g. `a==INT_MAX` would cause an overflow and **Undefined Behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix this is to `static_cast<long long>` because long long is 8 bytes and it is large enough to hold the information in the event of an overflow. An overflow occurs when you try to hold a number when you do not have enough bits to do so and as a result some of them get chopped off.

Here is an example without the warning:

```
std::cout << "Two roots: " << (-b - std::sqrt(d)) / (2 * static_cast<long long>(a)) << " "
          << (-b + std::sqrt(d)) / (2 * static_cast<long long>(a));
```

Answer (score -1):

It no longer shows the warning in VS2022.

Apparently Microsoft concluded it produces more noise than useful information.

See my answer to the similar problem you linked to here:
[Warning C26451: Arithmetic overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995817/warning-c26451-arithmetic-overflow)