# C++ pointer Warning: Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-' on a 4-byte value and then casting the result to an 8-byte value

Tags: c++, pointers

When I run this function, It gives me a 2 warning for `setw(*torPtr - *harePtr)` and `setw(*harePtr - *torPtr)`

It said :

> Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-' on a 4-byte value and then casting the result to an 8-byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '-' to avoid overflow (io.2).

How can I fix this please?

```
void Posi(const int* const tPtr,const int* const hPtr)
{
    if (*hPtr == *tPtr) {
        cout <<setw(*hPtr) << "bang!" << '\a';  
    }
    else if (*hPtr < *tPtr) {
        cout << setw(*hPtr) << 'H' << setw(*tPtr - *hPtr) << 'A';
    }
    else {
        cout  << setw(*tPtr) << 'T' << setw(*hPtr - *tPtr) << 'B';
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, everything looks ok https://wandbox.org/permlink/jfz1q5uZoUKoDcdS, the problem must be elsewere, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Wow, the error message complains about "casting" when there are no casts? The term here should be "converting". Compiler writers should know the difference.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308422/arithmetic-overflow-using-operator-on-a-4-byte-value-then-casting-the-resul ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Visual Studio, I get this error as well.
After looking into `setw` that I linked from `#include <iomanip>`, I found that `setw` is provided with a parameter `streamsize` which is actually a `long long`.

The resulting problem seems to be that you are trying to cast the arithmetic result of two `int` (with a size of 4 bytes) to a `long long` (with a size of 8 bytes) to conform to the definition of `streamsize` in `setw`.

An overflow caused by an arithmetic operation would not yield correct results.
If you want to learn, how an overflow is caused, you could look at the following web-article https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/.

To fix the problem, you will need to prevent the overflow from occuring, which can be achieved by casting the values to a larger data type. For example:

```
const long long value_cast = static_cast<long long>(*tPtr) - static_cast<long long>(*hPtr);
cout << setw(*hPtr) << 'H' << setw(value_cast) << 'A';
```

I hope that this answers your question. :)

**Edit:**
I changed the cast from c-style to static. Thank you for your contribution [anastaciu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6865932/anastaciu)!

Comment: Well spotted, that seems to be it, since this is C++ it would be best to use C++ style cast `static_cast<long long>(*tPtr)`, etc.

Comment: The answer is working. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: FYI: despite the (erroneous) use of the word "casting" in the error message, there are no casts in the original code. There are **conversions**, and that's what the compiler should be complaining about. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. +1.