# Should I pay attention this warning that Visual Studio gives me?

Tags: c++

I have a 32-bit integer called `dim`, and I'm reserving an array of unsigned chars using `new` that's `dim` * `dim` * `dim` big. Visual Studio says I should cast `dim` to a 64-bit integer before doing this, but I feel like it doesn't really matter.

```
unsigned char* cells = new unsigned char[dim * dim * dim];
```

```
C26451: Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2).
```

`dim` isn't going to be bigger than 1000.

Comment: If dim can be 1.000, then dim * dim * dim can be 1.000.000.000, which is beyond at least the smaller implementations of `int`.

Comment: @Yunnosch The warning tells us that `int` is 4 bytes, as it always is on modern Windows.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `dim` isn't going to be bigger than 1,000, the largest your expression can be is 1,000 × 1,000 × 1,000 — also known as 1,000,000,000. This fits into a 32-bit integer (which your `int` apparently is), so your program does not risk an overflow.

However, the compiler doesn't know this. Sometimes it has enough information to "prove" these constraints itself; sometimes it doesn't. Apparently, here, it doesn't. And, since your "argument" to the array dimension is a 64-bit integer, it's telling you that — if you *did* potentially have larger `dim` values — you could reduce the risk of an *avoidable* overflow by pre-casting to the type you're going to end up with anyway.

(Of course if your expression could end up larger than *Uint64.Max* then all bets would be off, no matter what you did.)

Questions about C26451 come up from time to time because it does seem to be a little overzealous [on occasion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55995817/4386278). Personally I'd consider disabling it, but if you subscribe to the "never disable a warning" category of people, just do as it says. It won't really hurt you, and this particular suggestion *is* arguably a good habit to get into.

Answer (score -1):

You should pay attention to the warning; [`operator new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) expects an array size value of [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Comment: And? So? Therefore?

Comment: And so, therefore, provide it with an array size value of `std::size_t`.

Comment: That's literally what the OP is doing (via implicit conversion). You did not address the question at all, which is about overflows and the veracity of warnings.

Comment: The question was "Should I pay attention (to) this warning that Visual Studio gives me?".